# How to to get Property Types of a NDB Model in GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

**[Added Solution at the end of question]**

How to to get Property Types of a NDB Model in GAE Python ?

Example model :

```
class X(ndb.Model): 
    prop_1 = ndb.IntegerProperty ("a", indexed=True) 
    prop_2 = ndb.StringProperty ("b") 
    prop_3 = ndb.DateTimeProperty ("c", repeated=True) 
    prop_4 = ndb.DateProperty ("d", repeated=False)
```

Using [GAE Metadata API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata) did not help.

I can get list of all properties of model `X` using [get_properties_of_kind(kind)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata).

But [get_representations_of_kind(kind)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata) would not help me get the property types as it has the same property representation values for more than one property type ( like `DateTime` and `Date` both have `INT64` ).

**ATTEMPT 1**

```
y = globals()["X"]  # IF I GET THE MODEL NAME AS STRING; ELSE y = X. 
logging.info (y) 
logging.info (vars(y)) 
for item in vars(y): 
    if (item[0]!="_"):  # ASSUMING ALL INTERNAL KEY NAMES START WITH "_". 
        logging.info ("item=["+item+"] ") 
        logging.info ("vars(y)[item]=["+repr (vars(y)[item])+"] ")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2015-03-02 00:08:43.166 +0530 I X<prop_1=IntegerProperty('a'), prop_2=StringProperty('b'), prop_3=DateTimeProperty('c', repeated=True)>
2015-03-02 00:08:43.171 +0530 I {'__module__': '__main__', 'prop_1': IntegerProperty('a'), 'prop_2': StringProperty('b'), 'prop_3': DateTimeProperty('c', repeated=True), '_properties': {'a': IntegerProperty('a'), 'c': DateTimeProperty('c', repeated=True), 'b': StringProperty('b')}, '_has_repeated': True, '__doc__': None} 
2015-03-02 00:08:43.186 +0530 I item=[prop_1]
2015-03-02 00:08:43.191 +0530 I vars(y)[item]=[IntegerProperty('a')]
2015-03-02 00:08:43.195 +0530 I item=[prop_2]
2015-03-02 00:08:43.200 +0530 I vars(y)[item]=[StringProperty('b')]
2015-03-02 00:08:43.204 +0530 I item=[prop_3]
2015-03-02 00:08:43.209 +0530 I vars(y)[item]=[DateTimeProperty('c', repeated=True)]
```

Using this approach, I would get the Property Types of a Model as String ( like, `DateTimeProperty('c', repeated=True)` ). I would have to extract the Property Type ( `DateTimeProperty` ) using regex.

Is this the correct ( and the best ) way to do it ?

**SOLUTION**
Based on answers by @Greg and @Alex Martelli, I was able to come up with a solution :

```
obj = globals ()["X"] 
for item in obj._properties: 
    logging.info ("b item=["+item+"] ") 
    # This gave the short names of properties :  "a", "b", "c", .. 

    logging.info ("b needed part = ["+obj._properties[item].__class__.__name__+"] ") 
    # This gave the property type class :  "IntegerProperty", "StringProperty", "DateTimeProperty", .. 

for item in obj.__dict__: 
    if (item[0]!="_"): 
        logging.info ("HB item=["+item+"] ") 
        # This gave the actual property name :  "prop_1", "prop_2", "prop_3", ..
```

**Note** that I could not use the [GAE Metadata API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata) since it needs at least one entity of the Model to be present, which is not necessary in my case.
In my situation, I need to create the class name from string ( hence the globals().. ).

**Only problem**, now, is how to correlate actual property names ( like "prop_1" ) to the obtained property types ?  Right now, the short names ( like "a" ) map to property types.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a model class, then its `_properties` attribute will contain the attributes that are datastore-properties. From there, you can access the `__name__` of the class and/or any other attributes of the Property.

You don't need to be accessing `globals()` or `vars()` like you're doing, and there's definitely no need to resort to regex.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question with the solution. Please let me know your views.

Answer (score 3):

If any entity of model class `X` exists, I would recommend:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import metadata

props = metadata.get_properties_of_kind('X')
prop_to_type = {}
for p in props:
    prop_to_type[p] = type(getattr(X, p))
```

If no entity of model class `X` exists, `props` will be the empty list, so you may have to resort to slightly trickier approaches such as

```
props = X._property
```

In this case, `props` is a `dict`, and its values are **instances** of property classes -- but you can still loop on `props` (getting the dict's keys, which are the property names) and use the same `type(getattr(...` code as above to get the actual types.

I nevertheless consider this "slightly trickier" because in Python it's generally considered better to avoid accessing names that start with an underscore, when feasible!-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with the solution. Please let me know if that is not the right approach.

Comment: @gsinha, `obj = globals ()["X"] ` makes no sense -- `obj = X` is equivalent and much simpler and more obvious.  Other criticisms of your solution are already expressed in my answer you're commenting on and I won't repeat them needlessly.  Still, your code should work -- until it doesn't, and then, have fun debugging it:-).

Comment: I genuinely appreciate that you took time to reply again. I have implemented backup+restore of GAE entities to GCS files using json dumps ( and handle non serializable types like datetime ). While restoring entities, after a data loss, there might not be any entity of that model in NDB. For recreation of entity, in a generic way for all models, I would need to read the property names and assign values from the GCS file ( json loads ). In GCS file, everything ( `model name`, `property names`, values ) is `string`. Hence, the indirect way `obj = globals ()["X"]` instead of `obj = X`.